# Android java jsoup take text from the father but not from the children

Tags: java, android, parsing, web-scraping, jsoup

I have the following html code, I just need to take the `message` text and assign it to the `message` variable in java.

But I'm not succeeding, in this case it also takes the text of the child, returning the text "Message data".

Can you give me a hand?

html:

```html
<span class="milestone-primaryMessage beta">
Message <span class="nowrap">Data</span>
</span>
```

Java:

```java
String message = ele.select(".milestone-primaryMessage").text();
String data = ele.select(".milestone-primaryMessage > .nowrap").text();
```

In JavaScript cheeriojs I do a similar thing, in js it works fine.

```js
const message = $($(el).find(".milestone-primaryMessage").contents().get(0)).text().trim(),
const data = $(el).find(".milestone-primaryMessage > .nowrap").text().trim()
```

Comment: What is `ele`? Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Maybe I found a solution I don't know if it's the best: `ele.select(".milestone-primaryMessage").get(0).ownText();`

Comment: It all depends on the html that you are trying to parse. If you have a single nowrap class then you can use `ele.select(".nowrap")`, but if you have multiple such classes in your document, you have to be more specific, which in your case is `ele.select(".milestone-primaryMessage > .nowrap")`. Anyway, I don't know which solution is "best", as sometimes there are multiple ways to get the same result.